# Smooth scroll + offset on function goToNext

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, offset, smooth-scrolling

I am wanting to add an offset from the top and smooth scroll to the following function, 
The functionality is on one button thats fixed and follows the user down the page. This button has to be able to scroll through numerous anchors and then go back to the first one, with an offset ideally of 105px from the top. trawled the net for hours for help and dont have the jquery know how myself to fix this, any help??
Similar example here - http://www.google.com/nexus/7/ (button in bottom right)

```
<script>
var max = 6;

function goToNext() {
    var hash = String(document.location.hash);
    if (hash && hash.indexOf(/anchor/)) {
        var newh = Number(hash.replace("#anchor",""));
        (newh > max-1) ? newh = 0 : void(null);
        document.location.hash = "#anchor" + String(newh+1); 
    } else {
        document.location.hash = "#anchor1";        
    }
}

</script>
<a href="#" onclick="goToNext();return false;"></a>

<div id="anchor1"></div>
<div id="anchor2"></div>
<div id="anchor3"></div>
<div id="anchor4"></div>
<div id="anchor5"></div>
<div id="anchor6"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it scroll *smoothly* to the element using `animate({scrollTop:value},delay)`.

```
$('document').ready(function () {
     //on DOM ready change location.hash to 'anchor1'
     window.location.hash = 'anchor1';
    //GO TO NEXT click event:
    $('a').click(function (e) {
        //preventing the default <a> click (href="#")
        e.preventDefault();
        //get the current hash to determine the current <div> id 
        var hash = window.location.hash,
            //find the (next) immediate following sibling of the current <div>
            $next = $(hash).next('div');
        //check if this next <div> sibling exist
        if ($next.length) {
            var id = $next.attr('id'),
                nextOffsetTop = $next.offset().top;
            //animate scrolling and set the new hash
            $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: nextOffsetTop}, 'slow');
            window.location.hash = id;
        }else{
        //else if the next <div> sibling does not exist move to the first anchor
            var first = '#anchor1';
            $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: $(first).offset().top},'slow');
            window.location.hash = first;
        }

    });
})
```

See this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LR9Cd/13/).

---

Then comes the ***flickering***. Actually it does not *flicker* but somewhat *jerky*, if you look closely into the code above. I am setting the `animate(scrollTop)` first, then changing the hash `window.location.hash = id`. Now when the animate starts scrolling and suddenly we are changing the hash it tends to jump directly to the next `<div>` (this is the default `haschange` event) but pulled back by the `animate()` and that causes the scrolling to be *jerky*.

We cannot just stop the default propagation of the `haschange` event, there may be a solution to do that but cannot guarantee that it would work on all browsers, each browser has different behaviour when it comes to the `haschange` event. But thanks to @Andy E solution on that SO post you've provided, we don't need to stop the haschange propagation. We can just simply change the hash first, reset it to last `scrollTop()` position then animate scrolling at will!

```
//get the current scrollTop value
var st = $(window).scrollTop();
//change the hash
window.location.hash = id;
//reset the scrollTop
$(window).scrollTop(st);
//animate scrolling
$('body, html').animate({scrollTop: nextOffsetTop}, 'slow');
```

Check this updated [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LR9Cd/14/).

---

Now let's talk about [**HTML5 History API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). The reason I didn't introduced this at first because it is implemented differently across HTML5 (especially IE) browsers and has no fallback for HTML4 browsers, making this method somehow inconsistent. But you can get this done properly using a plugin I guess.

Here's how you can do it using `history.pushState()`:

```
if ($next.length) {
    var id = $next.attr('id'),
        nextOffsetTop = $next.offset().top;

    history.pushState({state:id}, id, '#'+id);
    $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: nextOffsetTop - 105}, 'slow');      
}
```

See this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LR9Cd/15/).

That's it. Cheers!

Comment: Im wanting the functionality on one button thats fixed and follows the user down the page. This button has to be able to scroll through numerous anchors and then go back to the first one, with an offset ideally of 105px from the top.

Is there a way to modify the code provided (thanks! It solves the scrolling issue) to scroll back to the top after the last anchor is hit?

Thank you for the answer :)

Comment: $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: nextOffsetTop - 105},'slow');

So by editing this I have my offset and my smooth scroll, but how to get it to repeat from the top once you reach the last anchor??

Comment: I see you want a top spacing of 105 before the elements offset. I've updated this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LR9Cd/8/).

Comment: And that works perfectly! Cant wait to stick it into the site and see it in all its glory. Many thanks Mark!!
Jquery wizards like yourself are awesome. Again many thanks!

Comment: I would upvote the hell out of of you if I could :( but im still a stackoverflow noob and dont have the rep >.<

Comment: Why is there no "Give this guy a medal for awesomeness" feature on this site?

Comment: Hey Mark, i wanna give you another chance to teach me wisdom :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880435/jquery-function-after-page-redirect?noredirect=1#comment31334832_20880435